# tabularx table and the indentation from the addmargin environment

Tags: margins, koma-script, tabularx

I have a problem with the indentation done by the addmargin environment of the koma script and the use of tabularx table. Clearly the `\textwidth` uses the original width of the text and not the smaller one of the addmargin environment.

So the desired output is that the table is left aligned with the `lipsum[1]` text and right aligned both with the `lipsum[1]` and `lipsum[2]` text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0pt}
    \lipsum[1]  
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{.2\textwidth}X}
    First column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
    Second column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabularx` is _very_ respectful and does what it's told, even if you tell it the wrong thing: use `\linewidth` not `\textwidth`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK I should have formulated it a bit different. It didn't mean that the package can't do it, but that I did not get the desired output with the settings I used.

Comment: I know, just joking with you:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\textwidth` doesn't change: you have to use `\linewidth` when inside a list (which `addmargin` is); moreover you have to remember `\noindent` and `@{}` for removing the padding on the left and right.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0pt}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{.2\textwidth}X@{}}
    First column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
    Second column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `tabularx` is not needed:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{addmargin}[2\parindent]{0pt}
\lipsum[1]  

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.2\linewidth}p{.8\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}@{}}
    First column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
    Second column & A long column which doesn't respect the margin added to the left of this page but goes into the margin on the right \\
\end{tabular}
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd just made an identical answer but I suppose I'll +1 yours since you were so kind to me earlier:-)