# \newenvironment or \newcommand for \xltabular

Tags: macros, environments

I'd like to have a shorthand to trigger a  table like tabularx, with multipage option like longtable. Neither `\newenvironment` nor `\newcommand` I can coax to work

The weird `@..` construction at the beginning of the setup of xltabular is for [discarding the indentation that is otherwise added](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190923/tabularx-table-and-the-indentation-from-the-addmargin-environment).
Everything before the actual document takes place in a class file, if that makes a difference. Interpreter needs to be XeLaTex.
There does not seem to be a command-version of begin/end xltabular, which is how the problem with environment is solved in [tabularx-cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42325/tabularx-inside-a-newenvironment).

M(n)WE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular} % mixture of tabularx and longtable 

%%  Either like this (1)
%\newenvironment{threetable}
%{\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{}}} {\end{xltabular}}

%% Or like this (2)
%\newcommand{\startthreetable}{\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{}}}
%\newcommand{\stopthreetable}{\end{xltabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{}}
Content & content & CONTENT
\end{xltabular}

%% (1)
%\begin{threetable}
%Content & content & CONTENT
%\end{threetable}

%% (2)
%\startthreetable
%Content & content & CONTENT
%\stopthreetable

\end{document}
```

Comment: not sure what you see weird in `@{..}` that is unrelated to xltabular it is basic latex syntax to specify intercolumn material and applies to `tabular` in the core format and has been in latex since the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the `tabularx` manual (`xltabular` is basically a wrapper around `tabularx` to incorporate `longtable`) you need to use the command form inside enviornment definitions

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltabular} % mixture of tabularx and longtable 

\newenvironment{threetable}
{\xltabular{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{}}} {\endxltabular}



\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{\hspace{20pt}} X @{}}
Content & content & CONTENT
\end{xltabular}


\begin{threetable}
Content & content & CONTENT
\end{threetable}


\end{document}
```

the `@{...}` construct here is not specific to any of these packages it is basic LaTeX syntax applying to `tabular` and all its extensions, it specifies inter-column material.

Comment: this is acutally something i tried. probably lost a } somewhere and figured it was a dead end. The resulting error messages seemed to be critical about the @. Wow. Thanks. About the 'weirdness' of the @: in the eye of the beholder, i.e.tardigrada have been with us 'from the start' as well, and qualify for weird as well.

Comment: if you could add a sentence or two in opening of your answer about packages inherit their behavior, i'd like to accept this answer after the obligatory wait.

Comment: @bukwyrm  There is no general  inheritance mechanism, the whole thing is specific to the way tabularx is implemented so I'm not sure what I could say. (also just at the moment I'd rather have +10 from an upvote than +15 from an accept, to get a nice total score:-) I don't think I have ever looked at the `xltabular` documentation before but it doesn't say much other than that it works like `tabularx`.

Comment: @bukwyrm I added something.

Comment: @bukwyrm well no latex syntax is that "natural" but I'm interested why you find `@{hello}` to put hello between columns more weird than other similar syntax like `p{1cm}` for a 1cm wide column or `>{\bfseries}` for a bold column.

Comment: - you are quite right -reflecting on it, most latex syntax is just deeply weird to me